# Azure Virtual Networks deletion issue

Tags: azure, cloud

I am trying to delete virtual networks and subnets in azure console, but it is giving me the response that subnet is in use, how to force delete resources.

I have tried to delete manually and using azure cli but the issue remains same.

Answer (score 0):

when I ran the comment to delete vnet I got the same error `subnet is in use` like below

```
(InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted) Subnet sub1 is in use by /subscriptions/209654ebxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/KHAN/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/VM2479/ipConfigurations/IPCONFIG1 and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet. Code: InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted Message: Subnet sub1 is in use by /subscriptions/209654eb-1xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/KHAN/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/VM2479/ipConfigurations/IPCONFIG1 and cannot be deleted. In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet. See aka.ms/deletesubnet.
```

[image]

This error usually occurs when there are dependencies or resources still associated with the subnet or virtual network you are trying to delete.

> This could include virtual machines, network interfaces, network security groups, route tables, Bastion or other resources. You cannot force delete a VNet if it is connected to other resources.

***In your virtual network under setting, `connected devices`*** in my case Network interface is connected.

In that Network interface my vnet/subnet is associated, and Network interface is attached to virtual machine. make sure to delete that vm and NIC or detaching network interfaces. You should first delete or disconnect those dependencies before attempting to delete the VNet.

Now when I run command vnet delete successfully like below:

```
az network vnet delete --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVNet
```

[image]

[image]

***Reference***:

[Create, change, or delete an Azure virtual network | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-virtual-network)

Comment: @Uzair Hussain let me know if you have any queries?